# What does “but […], though” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, colloquialisms

I asked my American friends about the meaning of this word, but none of them could answer definitely. Some of them said that you can say *though* if you're not sure about something. Some of them said that it couldn't be explained because it is slang.

I was in the restaurant one time and went to the bathroom. There were two closed doors and a girl standing in front of them with her cellphone. I asked if she was in line and she answered:

> I'm not in line, **but** they are both occupied, **though**.

What did she mean? Was she not sure about the doors?

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/though

Comment: Questions about such common, basic words would be more appopriate in our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It is odd that she put it at the dnd of the sentence.  The "but" earlier on is equivalent to "however"—so the "though" seems redundant.  What most likely happened is she got to the end of the sentence and had forgotten thst she had slready said "but", so just to be sure, she tossed in "though" at the end. This kind of thing (corrections, or even change of topic in mid-sentence)is not uncommon in spoken language.

Comment: @Barmar: OP is asking not so much about the meaning of "though" as about what it means to put "though" at the end of a sentence.

Comment: @Barmar The meaning of the word *though* and its contrast with the words *but* and *however* is actually the subject of much academic research. So, actually, this question is of serious interest to serious linguists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"though" in similar contexts (after a comma/pause) is common in the spoken language.

The speaker simply adds an additional piece of information. For example, here it means the same as "however".

Answer (score 2):

"though" at the end of a sentence is difficult to define or to explain. Somehow it has a restricting function.  The easiest way to understand it would be to look it up in a dictionary of English and your mother-tongue.
I try to find some examples that might clarify the meaning.

1 - Yes, he can drive a car. Actually he's a excellent driver. He is only 15 and has no driver's licence, though. - Remark: The sentence with though at the end has the same meaning as a sentence/clause with but/however at the beginning.

2 - Our team lost. It was a good game though. OALD

3 - Have you ever been to Australia? -- No, I'd like to, though. OALD

"though" is no slang word, that is not correct. But it is typical of spoken language.